# How to convert .wmf to .pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, arabic, wmf

How do I convert a .wmf "Arabic Language" file into a PDF?

I use this code

```
iTextSharp.text.Image img1 = ImgWMF.GetInstance(@"path.wmf");
Document pdfDoc = new Document(img1);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(@"path.pdf", FileMode.Create));
pdfDoc.Open();
img1.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
pdfDoc.Add(img1);
pdfDoc.Close();
```

But unfortunately the letters are flipped "Left to Right"

[image: Converted Wmf to PDF using ITextSharp]

PS: I tried other libraries and tools, but the quality of PDF image was too poor.

[image: Wmf2pdf converted using another tools]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with iText7 and the pdfCalligraph addon. This addon adds support for Arabic scripts.

Comment: Thank you! 

I solve my issue with another free library.

Comment: Which one did you use?

Comment: I found free DLL project  with source code, I change on the code to make it running as I want

Comment: Just out of interest though. Which library did you use?